# How can Split PDO query based on the condition in PHP .I want to execute only part of query and another part to be executed based on the php condition

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

```
  ##  I want to Convert this Mysqli code to the Pdo
```

##
This is Mysqli code in which i splited the Query based on the condition
i want to do it in PDO

```
    $query="UPDATE sitetext SET text1 = '$sitetext', email = '$email'";
    if(isset($logo))
     {
       $query.=",logo='$logo' WHERE id = 1";
     }
   else
   {
      $query.=" WHERE id = 1";
    }
     $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: mysqli != pdo (-;

Answer (score -1):

Simply change the mysqli_exec with a PDO::exec ?

```
$query="UPDATE sitetext SET text1 = '$sitetext', email = '$email'";

if(isset($logo))
{
   $query.=",logo='$logo' WHERE id = 1";
}
else
{
   $query.=" WHERE id = 1";
}

$result= $PDO_Object->exec($query);
```

Comment: Thanks it is Working